# Название разделителя при печатании

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется этот разграничитель, который устанавливает положение печатающейся буквы?

Answer (score 4):

Это **текстовый курсор**.

Текстовый курсор (а также по аналогии с печатной машинкой — каретка, англ. caret) в общем случае обозначает место, куда будет вставлен введённый с клавиатуры текст. Курсор обычно мигает для того, чтобы его можно было быстро найти в тексте — неподвижный курсор может оказаться сложноразличимым в большом тексте. Наиболее распространённая форма курсора в современных интерфейсах пользователя — вертикальная черта, по высоте соответствующая высоте строки текста и располагающаяся в начале знакоместа вводимого символа.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Курсор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Сам мигающий знак называется **"курсор"**.
Его текущее расположение - **"позиция курсора"**.